# GCM Push Notifications not getting recieved on Lollipop devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Ok,

I'm developing an android app which is enabled with **GCM** for **Push Notifications**.

I was having trouble getting push notifications on any device (lollipop / pre-lollipop) when on college wifi. I researched about it and found that the **port 5228, 5229, 5230** on my college's firewall (**Cyberroam**) were **closed**. So the administrator opened them and now I am **receiving** **push** **notifications**, but only on pre-lollipop devices. **Lollipop** & **Post-lollipop** devices still **aren't receiving** push notifications.

**No problem** occurs when i use the app on **cellular data** or on **private wifi (at my place).**

I'm not able to understand why this is happening.

**NOTE**: Interesting thing is that all **MI devices are receiving** push irrespective of their Android version.

Can someone explain what might be happening and solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate SO question kindlty refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437102/android-gcm-not-working-after-lollipop-update-on-device?rq=1)

Comment: No,  my problem is way more complicated viz. Phones are being registered with GCM id successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the **Cyberroam** was blocking all requests from the **GTalk** service. That is why push notifications were not getting through. It is resolved now.

Thanks